# How to make an html block cast shadow on only one side and/or follow non squared shapes

Tags: html, css

I've been playing around with the `box-shadow` style in css using the syntax

```
box-shadow : offset-x | offset-y | blur-radius | spread-radius | color
```

particularly with `offset-x=offset-y=0`. When doing this, I get a shadow on all 4 sides. I don't want that.

I want to make it cast shadow on only one or two sides of the box, is that possible?

Say that the box surrounds a non squared shape, the box has a transparent background with a `png` or `svg` inside that illustrates a non-rectangular shape. This box is overlayed onto a web-page. Is it possible to make the `box-shadow` instead follow the contour of the contents inside that div-block instead of the transparent div-block itself?

I mean, this just looks plain stupid:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8LbK.png)

Edit: Some example code as requested:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 

#example1 {
    background-color: transparent;
    padding: 10px;
    box-shadow: 6px 6px 21px -21px #CCC;
}
#example2 {
    background-color: transparent;
    padding: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 21px #CCC;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>box-shadow: 6px 6px 21px blur radius light-gray on lower right side:</h2>
<div id="example1">
<p>A light shadow on only two sides.</p>
</div>

<h2>box-shadow: 0px 0px 21px blur radius light-gray centered:</h2>
<div id="example2">
<p>This is what I want it to look like; a <u>centered</u> shadow but only cast on the right and the bottom, not on all four sides of the div block which has a <u>transparent</u> background.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: if you want help you must add your code

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [`drop-shadow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/drop-shadow) filter

```css
.box {
 margin:50px;
 width:200px;
 height:200px;
 background:linear-gradient(to bottom right,red 50%, transparent 0);
 filter:drop-shadow(10px 0 5px #000);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
</div>
```

Comment: Interesting, I'll experiment with linear gradients, perhaps I can make them do what I want. Perhaps one can render custom shadow shapes using inline SVG's as defined in html5.

Comment: The only challenge that remains is to get that shadow effect outside the div block as SVGs and other elements generally reside inside the div block.

Comment: @ProfitusMaximus do you have any screen of how you want it to be outside ?

Comment: My question was a bit generic so I have no screen to show right now. I was thinking more about the future when I get to do more advanced stuff. For now, I'm trying to make a custom shape cast a proper shadow by combining a bunch of rectangular shapes underneath it.

Comment: I just want it to look more proper because right now I have a bunch of boxes underneath and they show up before the contents of the frame are loaded which looks ugly. If at least I manage to remove the excessive shadows from these boxes, it won't look as ugly.

Comment: Inside the frame I have transparent background png's. It would be really cool if the shadow was centered and perfectly followed the custom shape of the frame and the silhouette of the transparent png. But that would mean that I would have a shadow that is both outside and inside the div block / iframe.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify `box-shadow` properties like below to get shadow only one or two sides of the box.

```css
.box-shadow
{
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px -2px #888;
          box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px -2px #888;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-shadow"></div>
```

Comment: Looks nice, but try something a little more subtle and with a box that has a transparent background. It should be overlaid on top of a page with text. I want shadow only on bottom and the right side and nothing on the top, nor the left. Not even a trace of that shadow.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to say like this? But cannot use transparent in SVG with shadow.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
.triangle-container{
        transform: rotate(-90deg); 
  }
   .triangle{
    fill: white;
    stroke: white;
    stroke-width: 1;
    filter: drop-shadow(-10px 5px 5px rgba(204,204,204,0.1));
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="triangle-container">
   <svg height="500" width="500">
      <polygon points="250,100 100,400 400,400" class="triangle" />
      Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
   </svg>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can do like this:

```
box-shadow: 10px 0 10px #333;
```

Answer (score -1):

There is many of the online tools which generates a ready css code as per your requirements.
[online generate box shadow css](http://www.webestools.com/css3-box-shadow-generator-css-property-easy-shadows-div-html5-drop-shadow-moz-webkit-shadow-maker.html)

Answer (score -2):

Yes it is possible, please take a look here https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/box-shadow/, you will find examples that will help you.

Comment: The information in the link looked promising, but when I tried for example,     "box-shadow: 6px 6px 21px -21px #CCC;", I get no shadow whatsoever.

Comment: Please run this code and see for yourself https://jsfiddle.net/g3x91Ljr/3/

Comment: You could try this:
https://jsfiddle.net/g3x91Ljr/8

I want that high radius blurred shadow on the bottom and the right but none whatsoever on the top nor the left. The div block has transparent background.

Comment: Does this do the job https://jsfiddle.net/g3x91Ljr/13/ ? Change the first two values to 6px, 6px if you want the square to have shadows closer to the bottom and right.

Comment: It looks better, but I would prefer the shadow to be centered and not offset. Changing to 6px 6px makes it cast a bit of shadow on the left and top sides.

Comment: What do you mean by centered? Like this https://jsfiddle.net/g3x91Ljr/14/ ?

Comment: I want it to look exactly like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/g3x91Ljr/16/

but with the top part and left part removed. I.e. 'box-shadow: 0px 0px 21px #CCC'

Comment: but there is still a shadow on the top and the left unfortunately. At least in Chrome which is what I'm using